Styling axes in polar plots of radiation patterns with PGFPlots
I would like to display radiation patterns in a polar coordinate system using pgfplots.
To achieve this, I want to generalize the argument of the macro \pgfmathparse{#1+15} in the following example, considering that I already have to provide the scale limit value using the ymin=-15 key.
Furthermore, I would like to generalize the rather cumbersome plotting parameters into a single style.
Expected Result
The following minimum working example should demonstrate the result I expect:
\documentclass[tikz,class=article]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
   ymin=-15, ymax=0,
   ytick={-15,-12,...,0},
   xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\unit{\degree}$,
   ylabel={$F\left(\theta\right)$, \unit{\dB}},
   xmin=-180, xmax=180,
   xtick={-180,-150,...,180},
   x dir=reverse,
   x coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+90},
   x coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-90},
   y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+15},
   y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-15},
   yticklabel style={anchor=east, xshift=-5.25cm},
   y axis line style={xshift=-5.25cm},
   ytick style={xshift=-5.25cm},
   ylabel style={anchor=south east, xshift=-2cm, yshift=-2cm},
   no markers,
   legend style={at={(-0.05,1.05)},
                 anchor=north east},
   ]
  \end{polaraxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The compilation result should look like this:

This example was created using answers and comments to the following questions:

Polar plot using pgfplots/tikz
Producing an a transducer directivity pattern with dB scale

Predefined Style (not working)
Here's an example of an attempt to define a style:
\documentclass[tikz,class=article]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\pgfplotsset{radiation_axis/.style={
 xmin=-180, xmax=180,
 xtick={-180,-150,...,180},
 x dir=reverse,
 x coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+90},
 x coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-90},
 y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+15},
 y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-15},
 yticklabel style={anchor=east, xshift=-5.25cm},
 y axis line style={xshift=-5.25cm},
 ytick style={xshift=-5.25cm},
 ylabel style={anchor=south east, xshift=-2cm, yshift=-2cm},
 no markers,
 legend style={at={(-0.05,1.05)},
               anchor=north east},
 },}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
   ymin=-15, ymax=0,
   ytick={-15,-12,...,0},
   xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\unit{\degree}$,
   ylabel={$F\left(\theta\right)$, \unit{\dB}},
   radiation_axis,
   ]
  \end{polaraxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

pdflatex produces warnings (referring to the line that closes the polaraxis environment):
Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis x is approximately empty;
enlarging it (it is [90.000000000:90.000000000]) on input line 40.

 [warning /pgfplots/warning/approx empty range enlarged]

Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty;
enlarging it (it is [15.000000000:15.000000000]) on input line 40.

The compilation result looks like this:

Attempt to Substitute Value Using \pgfkeysvalueof (not working)
Another example is provided to illustrate that the straightforward approach did not work with respect to substituting the plot limits:
\documentclass[tikz,class=article]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
   ymin=-15, ymax=0,
   ytick={-15,-12,...,0},
   xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\unit{\degree}$,
   ylabel={$F\left(\theta\right)$, \unit{\dB}},
   xmin=-180, xmax=180,
   xtick={-180,-150,...,180},
   x dir=reverse,
   x coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+90},
   x coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-90},
   y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}},
   y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}},
   yticklabel style={anchor=east, xshift=-5.25cm},
   y axis line style={xshift=-5.25cm},
   ytick style={xshift=-5.25cm},
   ylabel style={anchor=south east, xshift=-2cm, yshift=-2cm},
   no markers,
   legend style={at={(-0.05,1.05)},
                 anchor=north east},
   ]
  \end{polaraxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

pdflatex produces the following warnings:
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.33   \end{polaraxis}
...                      
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \edef 
l.33   \end{polaraxis}

The compilation result looks like this:


TikZ .style can accept an argument. So #1 refers to the argument of radiation_axis, set with radiation_axis=something (here it's empty).
With nested .code inside radiation_axis/.style you should replace (as usual with LaTeX) #1 by ##1
    x coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1+90},
    x coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1-90},
    y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1+15},
    y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1-15},

Example:
\documentclass[tikz,class=article]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\pgfplotsset{radiation_axis/.style={
    xmin=-180, xmax=180,
    xtick={-180,-150,...,180},
    x dir=reverse,
    x coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1+90},
    x coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1-90},
    y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1+15},
    y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1-15},
    yticklabel style={anchor=east, xshift=-5.25cm},
    y axis line style={xshift=-5.25cm},
    ytick style={xshift=-5.25cm},
    ylabel style={anchor=south east, xshift=-2cm, yshift=-2cm},
    no markers,
    legend style={at={(-0.05,1.05)},
      anchor=north east},
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
      ymin=-15, ymax=0,
      ytick={-15,-12,...,0},
      xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\unit{\degree}$,
      ylabel={$F\left(\theta\right)$, \unit{\dB}},
      radiation_axis,
    ]
  \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Following jlab's clarifications and suggestions, I will propose a comprehensive solution that also addresses the need for a uniquely defined lower scale limit.
\documentclass[tikz,class=article]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath}
\usepackage[integrals]{wasysym}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\pgfplotsset{radiation axis/.style={
 xmin=-180, xmax=180,
 ymin=#1,
 xtick={-180,-150,...,180},
 x dir=reverse,
 x coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1+90},
 x coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1-90},
 y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1+#1*-1},
 y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{##1-#1*-1},
 yticklabel style={anchor=east, xshift=-5.25cm},
 y axis line style={xshift=-5.25cm},
 ytick style={xshift=-5.25cm},
 ylabel style={anchor=south east, xshift=-2cm, yshift=-2cm},
 no markers,
 legend style={at={(-0.05,1.05)},
               anchor=north east},
 },}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{polaraxis}[
   radiation axis=-15, ymax=0,
   ytick={-15,-12,...,0},
   xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\unit{\degree}$,
   ylabel={$F\left(\theta\right)$, \unit{\dB}},
   ]
  \end{polaraxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


